# Error when deploying report to SSRS Server

Tags: excel, reporting-services, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I am creating reports using SSRS connecting to excel datasource (ODBC 32 bit). While its runs ok in the report builder, when deploying to the report server 2015 (64 bit), I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to create a 64 bit ODBC connection.

How can I get this connection to work?

Comment: Hopefully something in here could help. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c9722d4-8c14-49b4-9bbe-a8f9f1968c8a/an-attempt-has-been-made-to-use-a-data-extension-oledb-that-is-either-not-registered-for-this?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: SQL Server and WIndows Version and Edition details may matter here.  For instance, with some SSRS Editions, external data sources can only be SQL Server instances — no other source is supported.